# Percentage column in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

How to keep the percentage in IBM DB2?
Float or Decimal?

// this does not work, the data is not saved:

```
create table bms."t1"(
    "name" decimal(2,2)
);

insert into bms."t1"
    values(10.05);
```

Answer (score 0):

`decimal(2, 2)` means that you have two digits, with two digits to the right of the decimal point.  So, it would contain values from 0.00 to 0.99.

You would appear to want -- at least --

```
create table bms."t1"(
    "name" decimal(4,2)
);

insert into bms."t1"
    values(10.05);
```